# Appending new column and rows from web scrape loop

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests-html

What can I add to the end of my code to append a list of items to a dataframe as column 1 and the resulting webscrape data from a for loop to column 2 and match each of column 1's list items to the webscrape data? I'm trying to get -

```
col1    col2
url1    A Details
url2    B Details
```

The code I have is,

```
urls = ['url1','url2']

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from time import sleep
from random import randint

for link in urls:
  sleep(randint(11,23))
  headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36',}
  req = requests.get(link, headers = headers)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, features="lxml")
  for script in soup(["script", "style"]): 
    script.extract()    
    text = soup.get_text() 
    lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
    chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
    text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)
    print(text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to append your data to a list inside your loop and then create a dataframe from your two lists.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from time import sleep
from random import randint

#initializes empty lists to append data
url_list = []
details_list = []


for link in urls:
  sleep(randint(11,23))
  headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36',}
  req = requests.get(link, headers = headers)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, features="lxml")
  for script in soup(["script", "style"]): 
    script.extract()    
    text = soup.get_text() 
    lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
    chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
    text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)

    url_list.append(link) # appends links 
    
    if not text: 
        # if text is empty
        details_list.append('none') # appends text
    else:
        details_list.append(text) # appends text 


results_df = pd.DataFrame() # creates empty dataframe
results_df['col1'] = url_list # adds column to dataframe with URLs
results_df['col2'] = details_list # adds column to dataframe with details
```

Comment: That makes sense. I know it will work but one problem I am having is that for some reason the scraped data ends up as a ton of rows in the list 'url_list` I get 70 rows for data scrape from just two websites and not able to join the columns on `results_df`. Should only be getting two rows of data into that list.

Comment: Are you getting an error regarding the url_list and details_list not being the same length?

Comment: I am yes - the work around I came up with was using np.unique(details_list) to return just unique values.

Comment: @DreDay I added an if statement to handle empty text. This should fix your problem. If for any reason there are empty URLs you would need to implement something similar for the other list. Hope this helps.